# React native listview refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image][image]I am fetching contacts to show in listview. it is working fine.the problem is when i open the listview for first time it is showing empty.i manually scroll down to refresh listview to show all contacts.How to fix this issue?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please more details so i can understand and help you out

Please Give 'Key' attr to listview i think it will help

Comment: can you please explain how to refresh listview?

Comment: You can give  Key to list view and change key when you want to refresh it
also update dataSource values

Comment: I have added two screenshots for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for it
I found some link related to listview 
https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-how-to-use-the-listview-component-a0ec44cf1fe8

I thinks so 
First time you open model and pass data to empty dataSource 
But before dataSource get values the LIstview was renders so it will so blank.

You need to wait for data 

Or

Pass Key like...

`<ListView
...
        key={this.state.dataSource}
...

      />`
So when key param will update releted view will also update

Comment: Hi.it is not working..

Comment: Please add removeClippedSubviews={false} in listview
Like this 

<ListView
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          dataSource={dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) =>

Comment: its work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `removeClippedSubviews={false}` in listview Like this

```
<ListView removeClippedSubviews={false} dataSource={dataSource}.....
```

Comment: If possible please share the document or link where you refered